# Ubuntu joining windows active directory issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, realm

Im new to trying to get linux on active directory.

I got the linux pc to join the domain on the controller under computers the linux pc is listed with my other windows machines.

but on the linux pc I can only login as a linux user.

typing in domain\user or user@domain and then the password says incorrect password and im sure im typing it right.

Doesnt matter if i use the FQDN or the netbios name for the domain. in either format of \ or @.

[image]

SSH in doesnt work either with domain account.

```
ssh -p 23 twml\\administrator@192.168.2.40
twml\administrator@192.168.2.40's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

packages installed for AD:

```
realmd libnss-sss libpam-sss sssd sssd-tools adcli samba-common-bin oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir packagekit
```

following this guide:

```
https://computingforgeeks.com/join-ubuntu-debian-to-active-directory-ad-domain/
```

realm shows joined the domain on the linux pc.

realm list output:

```
root@ADTest:/home/twmlserver# realm list
lightfoot.noip.me
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: LIGHTFOOT.NOIP.ME
  domain-name: lightfoot.noip.me
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U@lightfoot.noip.me
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

controller shows the pc as joined:

[image]

what log files can help? paths?

only packages logs i see in my /var/log area that is newly installed is sssd and all the log files it makes are empty.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the log files after a failed login attempt?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: what log am i looking for? path that i can nano?

Comment: Using `nano` is not the best way to view logs. That's an editor, and you certainly not going to edit them. Better use something like `less` (like this: `less /var/log/auth.log`) or other viewers. When solving problems like this, you may need to consult several log files simultaneously; just look in the `/var/log` which are available and try all; after some time you'll get better which log files to watch for which problems. Also `grep` often helps to filter out unneccessary log records.